# Why the background worker keep report progress to the progresschanged event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the `DoWork`event first time i'm downloading all emails and it's reporting to the `ProgressChanged` event and updating the `listView(lvnf)`. Second time after it finished downloading all emails i click the button again this time i added break points on every line in the `DoWork` event it's no stopping there but it keep updating the `listView` in the `ProgressChanged` event what also make the program to be freeze everything is slow. How can it be it keep getting to the `ProgressChanged` event and keep updating the listView with many items ? I added a break point there in the `ProgressChanged` event it stop there all the time updating the listView but it's never stop in the `DoWork` event on the reportprogress line. I'm talking about the second time i click the button ! It's only happen on the second time after finished first time downloading all emails.

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Dowork event:

```
private MimeKit.MimeMessage newmsg = null;
private HashSet<string> downloaded = new HashSet<string>();

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        numberofallmessages = 0;
        using (var client = new Pop3Client())
        {
            client.Connect(textServer.Text, Convert.ToInt32(textPort.Text), ssl);
            client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
            client.Authenticate(textUser.Text, textPassword.Text);

            var uids = client.GetMessageUids();

            for (int i = 0; i < client.Count; i++)
            {
                if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }
                if (!downloaded.Contains(uids[i]))
                {
                    allMessages.Add(client.GetMessage(i));
                    newmsg = client.GetMessage(i);
                    downloaded.Add(uids[i]);
                    SaveFullMessage(client.GetMessage(i), i);
                    w = new StreamWriter(emailsIDSFile, true);
                    w.WriteLine(uids[i]);
                    w.Close();
                }
                int nProgress = (client.Count - i + 1) * 100 / client.Count;
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(nProgress);
            }

            client.Disconnect(true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        string anyerrors = "";
    }
}
```

progresschanged event

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pbt.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    pbt.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
    pbt.Invalidate();
    if (newmsg != null)
    {
        ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]
    {
      newmsg.From.ToString(),         
      newmsg.Subject,                 
      newmsg.Date.ToString() 

    }));
    }
}
```

The completed event

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (closingForm)
        this.Close();
    label8.Text = numberofallmessages.ToString() + "/" + "0";
    downloadedallemailsfirsttime = true;
    countMsg = 0;
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(emailsIDSFile);
    if (fi.Length > 0)
    {
        downloadedallemailsfirsttime = true;
        lines = File.ReadAllLines(emailsIDSFile);
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            seenUids.Add(lines[i]);
        }
    }
 }
```

What i did now and seems to be working so far is in `DoWork` event i'm sending the `newmsg` as object with the report progress and also make the `newmsg` `null`:

```
private MimeKit.MimeMessage newmsg = null;
private HashSet<string> downloaded = new HashSet<string>();

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        numberofallmessages = 0;
        countMsg = 0;
        using (var client = new Pop3Client())
        {
            client.Connect(textServer.Text, Convert.ToInt32(textPort.Text), ssl);
            client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
            client.Authenticate(textUser.Text, textPassword.Text);

            var uids = client.GetMessageUids();

            for (int i = 0; i < client.Count; i++)
            {
                if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }
                if (!downloaded.Contains(uids[i]))
                {
                    allMessages.Add(client.GetMessage(i));
                    newmsg = client.GetMessage(i);
                    downloaded.Add(uids[i]);
                    SaveFullMessage(client.GetMessage(i), i);
                    w = new StreamWriter(emailsIDSFile, true);
                    w.WriteLine(uids[i]);
                    w.Close();
                }

                int nProgress = (client.Count - i + 1) * 100 / client.Count;
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(nProgress,newmsg);
                newmsg = null;
            }

            client.Disconnect(true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        string anyerrors = "";
    }
}
```

And in the progress changed event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pbt.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    pbt.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
    pbt.Invalidate();
    MimeKit.MimeMessage mymsg = e.UserState as MimeKit.MimeMessage;
    if (mymsg != null)
    {
        ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]
        {
            mymsg.From.ToString(),         
            mymsg.Subject,                 
            mymsg.Date.ToString() 
        }));
    }   
}
```

But still it's not the right answer even if it's working.

Comment: Adding some spacing in your introduction will make it more readable. The way you transfer "newmsg" from the worker thread to the Main thread is totally wrong. In my concern of best practice of Background worker, you should use the ProgressChanged Event to update a progression indicator (like you do with your textbox) and use the workerCompleted to transfer the result which will update your UI (control or databound item), here your listview, only once.

Comment: @MarcoGuignard You right. I changed the code and reporting the newmsg in the reportprogress: backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(nProgress,newmsg); and after this line added the line: newmsg = null; if not in the progresschanged it will keep update the listView since it's not null on new messages. In progresschanged event i added: MimeKit.MimeMessage mymsg = e.UserState as MimeKit.MimeMessage; and then i'm checking if mymsg is null or not and then updating the listView with the mymsg.  And until now all the tests i did show it's working without a problem.

Comment: You should have to tune it up a little. This should look like ReportProgess(int, New Object(...)). You have to make a deep copy of the Object to be sure that it won't be "modified" by the second thread before the main thread read it in the ProgressChanged Event. Take a look here for more détails http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332632/how-to-send-more-arguments-in-c-sharp-backgroundworker-progressed-changed-event

Comment: @MarcoGuignard I didn't understand about the deep copy if you could show me how to do it in my code please ? I'm looking at the link you provided but not sure yet how to make it in my code.

Comment: In your particular case, I will use a Tupple (Of String, String, String) to transfer the From, Subject and Date with the userstate object. As it is the value you really need to process your event. Of course if it is a "downloaded" message you should send Nothing.

Comment: @MarcoGuignard sound hard to do. If you could show me solution here. Thank you.

Comment: You only need to make a copy of `mymsg` if it's mutable or `static`, and I suspect it's neither.

Comment: You have an example in the second answer in the link provided above. Difference between Value Types and Reference Types in memory assignment is one of the most first concept you have to learn in programming skill, maybe before the simple conditional test. Before you get it, just keep away of anything which look like multithreading to avoid a lot of trouble. It's better to have UI freeze than random crash and unexpected behavior, hard to reproduce and to debug. I give help and advice, not solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got one `private MimeKit.MimeMessage newmsg` that is shared between your `BackgroundWorker` and your `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged`. But `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` keeps changing `newmsg` in a loop; when it changes `newmsg` the old value is discarded and `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged` will never know what it was. You need to save the value of `client.GetMessage(i)` every iteration of the loop and tell `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged` what it was for each iteration.

First, remove this:

```
private MimeKit.MimeMessage newmsg = null;
```

Then in `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` call:

```
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(nProgress, client.GetMessage(i));
```

And in `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged` you want:

```
var newMsg = (MimeKit.MimeMessage)progressChangedEventArgs.UserState;
if (newMsg != null)
{
    ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]
    {
      newmsg.From.ToString(),         
      newmsg.Subject,                 
      newmsg.Date.ToString() 
    }));
}
```

Edit: If you want to call `ReportProgress` but exclude `client.GetMessage(i)` if it has already been reported, change `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` to:

```
MimeKit.MimeMessage newmsg = null;
if (!downloaded.Contains(uids[i]))
{
    ...
    newmsg = client.GetMessage(i);
}

backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(nProgress, newmsg );
```

Comment: Dour tried your solution now it's not working good again. Same problem as in my first question before edited. After first time started the backgroundworker and downloaded all emails and i didn't close the program i clicked again on the button to start the backgroundworker and it's now reporting(report progress) again all the emails not downloading them again but reporting them from the dowork event to the progress changed event and the var newMsg is not null and it keep updating the listView. But it shouldn't since there are should no be new emails yet.

Comment: I used a break point in the do work event and it's not downloading emails but it keep report progress the client.GetMessage(i) and keep updating the listView. Not sure why. Maybe since when i start over the backgroundworker and it's looping on the client.Count it's reporting it ? Not sure.

Comment: That sounds like a different issue; are you sure you want to call `backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(nProgress)` outside `if (!downloaded.Contains(uids[i]))`? That will report progress even if `uids[i]` has already been downloaded. What is the type of `uids[i]`?

Comment: I can move the reportprogress inside the if (!downloaded.Contains(uids[i])) but i wanted it out or also out of it so if there are no new emails the progress bar and percentages in the progresschanged event will move fast down. Even if there are some new emails i wanted to keep showing the progressbar and percentages moving back.

Comment: The uids type is: ILIST<string>

Comment: Maybe i can move the report progress inside the IF and then show something else to the user like a message if there are new or there are no new messages but i think the progressbar and percentages is also nice to display in any case.

Comment: I can use a flag inside the if (!downloaded.Contains(uids[i])) set it to true and then check in the progresschanged event if newMsg is not null and if the flag is true only then update the listView. Is that good solution ?