# How to use correctly delegated BackgroundWorker`s ReportProgress method? (BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress Method (Int32, Object))

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am an engineer on an O&M department. To make easier my job I often write codes. I know the fundamentals of object-oriented programming and I familiar with C#.
I successfully use 2008 version of it. In my current project I start dozen of BackgroungWorkers which invoke the same (BackgrounfWorker_DoWork) method in their DoWork. At the begining of the threads there is a delegate section where declared which backgroundworker`s ReportProgress method has to be invoked (switch/case). This mechanism had been worked perfectly until I put an instance of a class  (complex_data) - in which declared one int, one string and one Bitmap variable - to second parameter of ReportProgress/delegate method. By the theory it is possible to use a "reference value" as the second parameter of ReportProgress/delegate method
(I found this on this site : [How to send more arguments in C# backgroundworker progressed changed event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332632/how-to-send-more-arguments-in-c-sharp-backgroundworker-progressed-changed-event)),
but I every time get an exeption when execution is at the "ReportProgress(0, message);" line.
The exeption is : "A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in rdszm.exe,
           A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"
I do not understand where I did not use attentively some index. Any suggestion, help will be nice. Thanks.
George

```
public delegate void my_delegate_type_for_ReportProgress(int a, complex_data data);

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BackgroungWorker1.RunWorkerAsync("THREAD_1");
    BackgroungWorker2.RunWorkerAsync("THREAD_2");
    BackgroungWorker3.RunWorkerAsync("THREAD_3");
    BackgroungWorker4.RunWorkerAsync("THREAD_4");
    .
    .
    .
}


private void BackgrounfWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string name = (string)e.Argument;
    ANALIZE(name);
}

private void ANALIZE(string name)
{
    string str;
    complex_data message = new complex_data();



    my_delegate_type_for_ReportProgress ReportProgress = new my_delegate_type_for_ReportProgress(BackgroungWorker1.ReportProgress);

            switch (name)
            {
                case "THREAD_1":
                    ReportProgress = new my_delegate_type_for_ReportProgress(BackgroungWorker1.ReportProgress);
                    break;
                case "THREAD_2":
                    ReportProgress = new my_delegate_type_for_ReportProgress(BackgroungWorker2.ReportProgress);
                    break;
                case "THREAD_3":
                    ReportProgress = new my_delegate_type_for_ReportProgress(BackgroungWorker3.ReportProgress);
                    break;
                case "THREAD_4":
                    ReportProgress = new my_delegate_type_for_ReportProgress(BackgroungWorker4.ReportProgress);
                    break;
        .
        .
        .
                default:
                    break;
            }

            try
            {
                message.i = 0; message.str = ""; message.image_Bitmap = null;
                ReportProgress(0, message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

        }
    }

public partial class complex_data
{
    public int i;
    public string str;
    public Bitmap image_Bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Well, *message.str* is an *array of char* and *message.image_Bitmap* may also contains an *array of byte*.

Comment: The suggestion was inspirational for me and I found where I have mistaken. The provided code is good. I did a wrong cast of the e.UserState at ProcessChanged method.